# How to append the string used in Preprocessors

Tags: ios

I have #define preprocessor to define an IPAddress. I want to change the IPAddress from my application so that i may interact with another IPAddress. How can i achieve this

```
#define validateServerRequestURL @"http://192.168.1.85/"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the macro, but you can work around it by storing the macro in a `NSString` and then you can modify that string i.e. your `IPAddress`

Comment: yes but if i want to change my ip for string validateServerRequestURL @"http://192.168.1.85/xyz.asmx. where xyz.asmx should always be there

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as

```
#define URL [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:%@//xyz.asmx",IPAddress,PortNumber]
```

where IPAddress and PortNumber are other macros to save in a user default

Answer (score 0):

You can join macros by just mentioning the macro names beside the string.

E.g.

```
#define IPAddress @"http://www.apple.com"
#define validateServerRequestURL @"http://192.168.1.85/"IPAddress
```

At runtime `validateServerRequestURL` will be the concatenated string `http://192.168.1.85/http://www.apple.com`